# How to call an applet in another class's main method

Tags: java, applet

We are required to make an Applet (not JApplet) in class. I want to call my applet in another class's main method. How do I do this? I tried the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI myGui = new GUI(); //GUI is my applet class
    myGui.init();
    myGui.start();
}
```

This returns a null pointer exception, however. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the exception? And the code around the line where it occurs?

Comment: If you can then post some more code..

Comment: i bet the NPE is inside `GUI` class

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please refer the instructor to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  The fact the teacher specified AWT and not Swing indicates they should not be put in charge of teaching people.